# forEach loop finishes after the last line of code executes

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, discord.js

What I am trying to do here is essentially go through a bunch of saved messages in a database, check if they still exist and if they do not, delete them, so what I've done is it checks if the message exists and if not it pushes it into an array of all the non-existent messages, but the code is running in the wrong order, it runs the if statement before the loop finishes. So for example it would console log the 2 before the 1. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
const {
        reactionRoleInformation,
    } = require("../database-functions/reactionroles/reactionRoleInformation");
    const {
        deleteManyReactionRoles,
    } = require("../database-functions/reactionroles/deleteManyReactionRoles");
    
    module.exports.cacheMessages = async (bot) => {
        const messageArray = await reactionRoleInformation();
        let deletedMessagesIds = new Array();
    
        messageArray.forEach(async (message) => {
            try {
                await bot.guilds.cache
                    .get(message.guild)
                    .channels.cache.get(message.channel)
                    .messages.fetch(message.id);
            } catch (err) {
                deletedMessagesIds.push(message.uniqueId);
                return;
            }
        console.log(1) 
            await bot.channels.cache.get(message.channel).messages.fetch(message.id);
        });
    
        console.log(2) 
        if (deletedMessagesIds.length !== 0) await deleteManyReactionRoles(deletedMessagesIds);
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.forEach()` will not wait for async functions. Instead, use a combination of .map with Promise.all.

`await Promise.all(messageArray.map(async (message) => {...}));`

Comment: Is that the case for all loops or just .forEach() loops?

Comment: A for (or for..in, for..of) statement will wait between iterations and therefore the code after the loop will only run after all async tasks are done. However this changes the execution of async tasks from parallel to sequential.